# Mutliple Image Download

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, beautifulsoup, urllib

```
# libraries
import os
import urllib.request as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# neccesary things
save_folder="Images"
#img_links=[]
usr_agent={"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36"}
g_img="https://www.google.com/search?site=&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1873&bih=990&"

# Save folder

def folder():
    if not os.path.exists(save_folder):
        os.mkdir(save_folder)

# get_links
def get_links(data,number):
    img_links=[]
    searchurl=g_img+"q="+data
    response=requests.get(searchurl,headers=usr_agent).text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(response,"lxml")
    # results=soup.find_all("a",attrs={"class":"VFACy"},limit=number)
    results=soup.find_all("img", attrs={"class":"rg_i"},limit=number)
    for result in results:
        link=result.get("src")
        img_links.append(link)
    return img_links

# download_img
def download_img(data, links):
    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        img_name=save_folder+"/"+data+"{:06}.jpg".format(i)
        ureq.urlretrieve(link,img_name)

# main
def main(data,n_img):
    folder()
    link=get_links(data,n_img)
    download_img(data, link)

# Run
if __name__=="__main__":
    data=input("What are you looking for?\nData:")
    n_img=int(input("How many do you want?\nNumber:"))
    main(data,n_img)
```

Comment: I want to download image, And I wrote above code. This code download image but, there is nothing inside of image. Where is my error.? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! The statement of your question should be within the body of your post, instead of being in a comment. That way people can clearly find what you're asking for help with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this:

```
def download_img(data, links):
    for i, link in enumerate(links):
        img_name=save_folder+"/"+data+"{:06}.jpg".format(i)
        images = requests.get(link)
        with open(img_name, 'wb') as writer:
            writer.write(images.content)
```

And some variable names are defined out of scope